# How to debug the AppEngine local server from IDEA+Gradle?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm following the Udacity App Engine course but as the tinker, I'm following using Gradle and IDEA (Open Source edition).

I have setup the project successfully using the following build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

appengine {
    daemon = true
    downloadSdk = true

    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.7'

    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.7'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.7'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.7'
    testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.9.7'
}
```

I am running the local dev server from IDEA using a Gradle run configuration with the `appengineRun` configuration and stopping it using another task for `appengineStop`. This is working, but I have no ability to debug as the breakpoints I put are not hit.

I believe this issue with breakpoints is because IDEA has no idea (I am horrible at puns) that it has to hook into the jetty server that backs the AppEngine server, but this is a wild shot as I have no knowledge of IDEA's internals, much less of how it handles Gradle executions.

How can I regain breakpoint ability? Is it feasible without a custom plugin?

Comment: Did you ever discover a better way of doing this? As it's a little annoying having a two stage process for debugging.

Comment: Nope. I was just curious of Java web development so i barely scratched the surface on it. .Net developer at heart. Sorry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you have to set the JVM debug parameters in your `build.gradle` file so that you are able to debug the local development server remotely.

```
appengine {
    ...
    jvmFlags = ['-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000']
}
```

Then you need to create a run/debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA (based on the above parameters) to be used for remote running or debugging processes. Remote running/debugging enables you to connect to a running JVM.

You can find more details [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-remote.html). But basically go to the **Run / Edit Configurations...**, in the dialog box click on **Add New Configuration** (+) and select **Remote**. Make sure that the configuration matches JVM flags (especially port). Save and close the dialog box.

Start your local development server and connect debugger (**Run / Debug**).

Answer (score 1):

**Configuration**

Put jvmFlags on build.gradle

```
  appengine {
        run {
            jvmFlags = ['-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000']
        }
    }
```

**Debug**

- On Gradle execute appengineRun and wait to server start

  - Select Run \ Attach to process... to attach to the server and debug