# How can I enable debugging with breakpoints in IntelliJ for gradle based Google App Engine project?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, gradle

I have created a Google app engine project using **gradle** and am using **IntelliJ** for implementation.

I am able to run the application using gradle task but when I try to debug it the application doesn't stop at the break points.

The debugger always seems to be listening at a different port.

I have added the following JVM flags in gradle.build but with no luck.

```
jvmFlags = ['-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999']
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24943787/3029175) answer. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a run/debug configuration by going to the drop-down for your run configurations in the toolbar. Use the 'Google App Engine Dev Server' configuration and you don't need to worry about setting the jvmFlags. I have written many Gradle/App Engine projects and have debugged them this way without issue.

[image]

[image]

You will need to specify your app engine application server. If you hit the ... next to the drop-down you can navigate to where you have it downloaded. I have always used the app-engine gradle task to download gradle. Then you find the latest app engine download in your .gradle directory.

Comment: this won't work with the community edition of IntelliJ. I think the OP is looking for a way with remote debug, respectively a way to tell the jvm which debug port to use via gradle.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think about the community edition when I answered. Sorry for the lack of help. If you are a student you can get a full license for free, obviously to only be used for school/personal. Otherwise make your company get you a full license.